# On the definition of algebraic dimension

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

In the book of complex geometry by D. Huybrechts, the algebraic dimension of a compact connected complex manifold $X$ is $\mathrm{a}(X):=\mathrm{trdeg}\mathcal{K}(X)$  over $\mathbb{C}$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is the complex number field and $\mathcal{K}(X)$ the function field of $X$. By Siegel's theorem, one knows that $\mathrm{a}(X)\leq \mathrm{dim}(X)$, so what if we omit the condition of compactness? In the case, how to define algebraic dimension of a connected complex manifold? In other words, my question is that whether the compactness condition of above definition is necessary or not.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dear @Moos, there are no generic points on non-quasi-projective manifolds...

Comment: The concept of algebraic dimension is not as well-behaved in the non-compact case; even what the 'correct' definition should be is not obvious (to me). One attempt, from the geometric point of view (which makes the dimension bound true by definition) would be to take the maximum of the dimensions of quasi-projective manifolds which are dominated by $X$ via a meromorphic map, with an appropriate definition of *meromorphic*. This, however, is far from what the transcendence degree of the function field measures unless $X$ is compact.

Comment: @Ben ok, I post this question because on that book there is a proposition which asserts that for a connected complex manifold X, if the canonical ring R(X) is not equal to the complex number field C, the Kodaira dimension of X is less than or equal to the algebraic dimension of X. But the existence of the algebraic dimension of X is not obvious to me, and I don't know how to guarantee the existence. Anyway,thank you very much!

Comment: Most parts of the book deals (as almost every complex algebraic geometry book does) with compact manifolds only. If something is unclear for non-compact ones, it's not going to hurt in further reading to add the compactness assumption.

Comment: Let me note that I'm not claiming that my proposed definition above is a good one; it's just the only reasonable one I see which makes the dimension bound hold. From a formal point of view, there is nothing wrong with the function field definition; it's just going to be infinite, in general (I think).

Comment: @Ben yeah, to avoid any confusion,it's better to admit the compact assumption. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

WE can define the algebraic dimension of $X$ as follows

For any compact connected
complex manifold $X$ the algebraic dimension $a(X)$ is described as

$$a(X) = max\{\kappa(L);L ∈ PicX\}$$

where $\kappa(L)$ is the Iitaka dimension of the line bundle $L$ and $ PicX $ is the Picard
variety of $X$ and the Iitaka dimension can be defined as follows

$$\kappa(L)=\limsup_{m\to \infty}\frac{\log dim H^0(X,L^{\otimes m})}{\log m}
$$

Moreover, $a(X)=dim X$ if $X$ is projective algebraic.

In fact $a(X)$  measures how many meromorphic
functions exist on $ X$

For any $ X$, there exists a projective algebraic manifold $ Y $ and a surjective
meromorphic map $ f : X → Y $ which induces an isomorphism for the meromorphic function fields of $ Y $ and
$X, $ so that $dim Y = a(X)$; the meromorphic map $f : X → Y $ is called the algebraic reduction of $X$, and is known
to be unique under a bimeromorphic equivalence. Moreover, fibers of $f $ are necessarily connected.

See Daniel Barlet paper

https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02238

Comment: Please avoid performing a large number of minor edits in a short amount of time: they bump questions/answers to the main page and it is often unnecessary.

Comment: The result of Orlov works for the algebraic dimension about derived bounded category of coherent sheaves i.e., $D^b(X)\cong D^b(X')$ ===> $a(X)=a(X')$